# Python list to split and only pull certain items to make a new list

Tags: python-3.x, list, split

I've used python to connect to a SQL server to execute a query.
I have a current list showing something like the below sample:

```
[('TEST', 'dbo', 'XXX', 'Practice', 1, 'char', 3, 3, None, None, 1, None, None, 1, None, 3, 1, 'YES', 39)
('TEST', 'dbo', 'XXX', 'ParPracticeCode', 1, 'char', 3, 3, None, None, 1, None, None, 1, None, 3, 2, 'YES', 39)
('TEST', 'dbo', 'XXX', 'PracOnlyName', 12, 'varchar', 100, 100, None, None, 1, None, None, 12, None, 100, 3, 'YES', 39)]
```

However, I would like to split the list and create a new list by including only the 4th item such as `Practice`, `ParPracticeCode` and `PracOnlyName`. 
so it becomes, new_list = `[Practice, ParPracticeCode, PracOnlyName]`

Comment: Why did you not use a for loop to get the 4th element? [for-loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) Why not using a  [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) ? Why no attempt - the problem is quite trivial and basic list operation can be found on about page 3 of any python tutorial you use to learn the language?  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - what you need to index into a list can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 1):

```
sample = [('TEST', 'dbo', 'XXX', 'Practice', 1, 'char', 3, 3, None, None, 1, None, None, 1, None, 3, 1, 'YES', 39), ('TEST', 'dbo', 'XXX', 'ParPracticeCode', 1, 'char', 3, 3, None, None, 1, None, None, 1, None, 3, 2, 'YES', 39), ('TEST', 'dbo', 'XXX', 'PracOnlyName', 12, 'varchar', 100, 100, None, None, 1, None, None, 12, None, 100, 3, 'YES', 39)]
new_list = [x[3] for x in sample]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [('TEST', 'dbo', 'XXX', 'Practice', 1, 'char', 3, 3, None, None, 1, None, None, 1, None, 3, 1, 'YES', 39),
     ('TEST', 'dbo', 'XXX', 'ParPracticeCode', 1, 'char', 3, 3, None, None, 1, None, None, 1, None, 3, 2, 'YES', 39),
     ('TEST', 'dbo', 'XXX', 'PracOnlyName', 12, 'varchar', 100, 100, None, None, 1, None, None, 12, None, 100, 3, 'YES', 39)]
```

Write a for loop to access the  '4' the value of each element in list like a 2D matrix

```
new_list = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    new_list.append(x[i][3])
```

This implementation will do

Comment: Why not simply use `for elem in x:` ? that would be better then indexing into the `x` again ... or a simple list comprehension liek Afloroale did?

Comment: I didn't  think of that.List comprehension will be best way to implement it.